# VS Code Regex Search and Replace Issue

Tags: regex

this is my first post and I hope i follow the guidelines for asking a question.

I am trying to do a search and replace operation in VS Code with Regex.

Input looks like:

```
TextA TextOne
Text
Text
TextB TextTwo
Text
TextC TextThree
TextA TextFour
Text
TextB TextFive
TextC TextSix
...
```

Output ideally:

```
TextOne, TextTwo, TextThree
TextThree, TextFour, TextFive
...
```

What i tried so far does not work well:

```
Search: TextA(.*) | TextB(.*) | TextC(.*)
Replace: $1, $2, $3
```

I am facing three problems:
(1) Sometimes there is no TextC in the input, in this case an output value of 0 would be great.
(2) How to get rid of the rest of the text.
(3) How to get all three texts in the output in one line (goal is a .csv-file).

Does anybody know how to solve one or all issues within the Regex statement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you replacing in files (the maginifying glass) or using in-document search and replace?

Comment: Maybe 1) `[\w\W]*?TextA\s*(.*)\n(?:[\w\W]*?\n)?TextB(.*)(?:\n(?:(?:(?!TextA)[\w\W])*?\n)?TextC(.*))?|(?:(?!TextA|TextB|TextC)[\w\W])+$` => `$1,$2,$3\n`, 2) `,$` => `, 0` and then 3) `\n,, 0$(?![\w\W])` => `<empty>`

Comment: Its hard to answer the question, because I don't know what you are replacing. Maybe try posting an image that shows the editor, and how your trying to use the search/replace tool. (Which is a great tool BTW) VSCode is so sweet!